# Breaking a tough password using john

Tags: password-cracking, john-the-ripper

I'm trying to crack a pretty advanced password on my computer and I've had it running for about a day on john's default settings.

Its gotten through roughly (a day times 23000kp/s) passwords.

I have tried check how many characters it has totally exhausted, but its going in a default funky order so its difficult to tell.

How would I optimise john to break this faster, considering the passwords it has tried?

Comment: Would there be a specific setting for cracking a good password (i.e. prioritise 8 characters alpha-num-sym first)? Also, is my computer far to much of a potato to handle this?

Comment: Can you expand on what "advanced" means in this context? If you know something about how the password was constructed, you can try to match that in the attack. (And the "funky order" is john's built-in Markov - basically running characters in order by how often they appear together in common passwords)

Comment: I don't know anything about how it is constructed, but it is not a bad password, it is meant to be pretty secure